# Rockstar language parsing Proper Variables

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to properly regex Proper Variables in [Rockstar Language](https://codewithrockstar.com/)?

I'm writing [syntax highlight extension](https://github.com/ra100/vscode-rockstar-language) for vscode. But it's kind of in conflict with String literals, where anything that is after the keyword "says " should be a string.
But when combined with Capitalized words, it's detected as Proper Variable.

This is regex of how far I got:

```regex
(?!(Say|Shout|Whisper|Scream|Listen( to)?|Put|If|Until|Build |Take it to the top|Knock |While|Continue|Break it down|My|Your|A|An|The)\\s)\\b((?<!says .*)([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\\s?)+)\\b($|\\s)
```

Problem is, that non-fixed length lookbehind `(?<!says .*)` doesn't work in vscode for parsing syntax.

[Example code snippet on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KC1gHi/1)

So how to make this work? Some ideas on how to not use that lookbehind?
Point is that in

```
Eleanor Rigby says Hello San Francisco
```

`Eleanor Rigby` should be Variable
`says` should be assignment
and `Hello San Francisco` should be string

But without lookbehind it considers `Hello San Francisco` as variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to consume the part you don't want and to use a capture group to identify it (and obviously to apply a particular treatment to it):

```
\b(?:(\bsays [A-Za-z\s]+)|(?!(?:Say|Shout|Whisper|Scream|Listen(?: to)?|Put|If|Until|Build|Take it to the top|Knock|While|Continue|Break it down|My|Your|An?|The)\s)\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*(?!\S))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LAHbvS/1)

Comment: That looks promising, I'll just add one more capture group, to separate "says" from the string itself
`\b(?:(\b(says) ([A-Za-z\s]+))|(?!(?:Say|Shout|Whisper|Scream|Listen(?: to)?|Put|If|Until|Build|Take it to the top|Knock|While|Continue|Break it down|My|Your|An?|The)\s)\b([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*)(?!\S))
`